# Can't Embed Image on Magento Product description page

Tags: product-images, magento1.9.3, media-images

Often this community is my destination for many issues. Recently we are facing an issue with our **Magento 1.9.3** store after upgrading it from **1.7.x** when we try to embed a picture or anything on the product description page. It never loads the popup correctly as this picture-

[image]

1. When we try to upload a picture on the product description
2. click the Insert/Edit image button
3. Popup comes but never complete where we can finish it.

I will really appreciate and will be grateful if someone advises how we can solve this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: what you getting in console log ?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am checking will come back with details info. Thank you!

Comment: From our more investigation, we have found it may happen due to CDN.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**  This issue was due to SSL & CDN configuration mismatch from the admin panel. With few changes, it's working perfectly. here is our current configuration which is working just fine- 
[image]

Thank you all.